# Azure resource group Template download

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I have a resource group with 20 resources(SQL, Web App ....)

[image]

I could not see the Resource group template while clicking the automation script button.

[image]

How can i download all the resource as a template?

It has, one failed deployment resource.
is there any way to get all resource template if i remove from there?

Comment: Do you try use Power Shell to export the template? For example`Export-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName ExampleGroup`

Comment: You could view template  from deployment history. Please refer to this [link]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template#view-template-from-deployment-history).

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the **Automation script** all the resources ready to export as a template, except the resources which has errors.

Click on the deployment which has error message and delete.

For downloading, you have both options:

- Click on **Download** option to store it into local machine.
- Click on **Add to library** to save as a template.

[image]

Automate deploying resources with Azure Resource Manager templates in a single, coordinated operation. Define resources and configurable input parameters and deploy with script or code. Learn more about [template deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy).

Comment: Thanks, It is not loading like the above. while clicking the Automation script it is progress par loading 30 sec then comes as empty  which is shared my second screen. but my other resource group are loading properly & can able to download it.

Comment: @sankara pandian Could you re-try in different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of things have changed from 2017 to 2020, but I just want to add this, so that its helpful for others who are looking for help for downloading templates

Goto Resource Groups and select the resource
In the Settings section, click on Export Template

[image]

The templates zip file is downloaded into your windows downloads directory.
Thanks
Nate